# Collision detection: Why is other object's offset so large?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to cycle through each div on drag and calculate whether they intersect or not based on their offsets. The draggable div's offset is calculated correctly, but the other divs register as a crazy big number (100,000). What am I doing wrong?

```
$(function() {
$(".table").draggable({
  drag: function(ev, ui)
  {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $(this).attr("id", "currentDrag");
    $(".table").not("#currentDrag").each(function() {
      var otherOffset = $(this).offset();
      if(offset.left + 100 > otherOffset.left)
      {
        console.log("collision");
        console.log("drag Offset: " + offset.left);
        console.log("other Offset: " + otherOffset.left + 100);
      }
    });
  }
});
});
```

http://jsbin.com/coxemuqogo/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

Notice how all the large numbers end in 100. This is because when you add a number to a string the number is converted to a string. With the order of operations going left to right you get:

```
'other Offset: ' + 11 + 22 = 'other Offset: 1122'
```

because the 11 is added to the string then the 22 is added to the string containing the '11'.

what you want is this:

```
'other Offset: ' + (otherOffset.left + 100)
```

this means that the number are added together before they are added to the string.